# How do I tell the MVC middleware that my class is a Controller in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, controller, asp.net-core-mvc

How do I tell the MVC middleware that my class is a Controller in ASP.NET Core?

According to the `ASP.NET Core in Action` book:

> Controllers are ordinary classes, though they often inherit from the Controller base class to provide
>   access to a number of helper methods, as shown in the following listing.

I thought that we tell the MVC that our class is a controller by inheriting from the `Controller` class. But now I see that I was wrong and the inheritance of the `Controller` class is optional.

That means there is something else that makes the MVC middleware consider classes as controllers and their methods as action methods and, hence, makes the MVC middleware check the corresponding classes and methods against an incoming request path. But I can not understand or find on internet what this is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is very possible. You don't need to inherit from `Controller` or `ControllerBase` For example, you can simply do this:

```
public class ProductController{}
```

The key here is to the suffix **Controller**.

Or you can use the `ControllerAttribute`. Like this:

```
[Controller]
public class Product{}
```

There are some other ways to achieve this.

Comment: I would really appreciate if you could point me to a place in the MSDN. :)

Comment: Also, what namespace is the class `ControllerAttribute` situated in?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerattribute?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: And do you know whether or not the `...Controller` suffix is documented?

Comment: @SasukeUchiha That practice is an example of "Convention over Configuration". Asp.net core will automatically detect your class as a controller.

Comment: But is that statement documented anywhere? I mean this statement: `Asp.net core will automatically detect your class as a controller by the '...Controller' suffix`.